# Prevent movement of top item in VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build widget with what I imagined to be a fair simple layout.

```
 ___________________
|                   |
| Title.            | 
| Subtitle          |      Static Content (more or less)  
|___________________|
|                   |
| 1           Today |
|                   |
| 2        Tomorrow |      Dynamic Content
|                   |
| 3       In 1 hour |
|___________________|
```

The issue is if any of the dynamic content is too big, it *pushes* the top content bar out the top of the widget, whereas I'd rather it grew out of the bottom. I can demonstrate this with this example:

[image] [image] [image]

As you can can see, as green gets too big, it pushes pink off the screen. I can't find a way to fix this.

I've tried `ZStack(alignment: .top)`, I've tried `layoutPriority`, I've tried `fixedSize` and I've tried `Spacer`

Answer (score 1):

Your `GeometryReader` answer works because `GeometryReader` aligns its content to the top by default. But since you don't use the `proxy` var, it might make more sense to use an [`overlay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(alignment:content:)) instead.

```
Color.clear.overlay(alignment: .top) { /// set alignment to `.top`!
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.pink)
            .frame(height: 40)
            .overlay {
                Text("Height: 40")
            }
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .frame(height: 180)
            .overlay {
                Text("Height: 180")
            }
    }
}
```

If you need to support iOS 13-15, try [`overlay(_:alignment:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chart/overlay(_:alignment:)):

```
Color.clear.overlay(
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.pink)
            .frame(height: 40)
            .overlay {
                Text("Height: 40")
            }
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .frame(height: 180)
            .overlay {
                Text("Height: 180")
            }
    },
    alignment: .top
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but this worked:

```swift
GeometryReader { proxy in
    
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.pink)
            .frame(height: 40)
            .overlay {
                Text("Height: 40")
            }
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .frame(height: 180)
            .overlay {
                Text("Height: 180")
            }
        
    }
}
```